# Identify the correct options for $f(r,\theta)=(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to \Bbb{R}^2$ be the function $$f(r,\theta)=( r\cos \theta,r \sin \theta)$$ Then for which of the open subsets $U$ of $\Bbb{R}^2$ given below, f restricted to $U$ admits an inverse?

1. $U=\Bbb{R}^2$
2. $U=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb{R}^2 : x>0, y>0\}$
3. $U=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2<1\}$
4. $U=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : x<-1, y<-1\}$

I think option 2 and 4 are correct since the Jacobian of the map will be $r$ and it will be non zero at every nbd of a non zero (x,y) and thus by IFT inverse will exists. Am I right?

Comment: Are we necessarily looking for a *continuous* inverse?

Comment: no there's no such requirement

Comment: Where is this question from? I've seen it at least four or five times in the past few days...

Comment: @JoeyZou Hi, this problem came in CSIR NET-JRF'15( an exam in India)

Answer (score 1):

Your argument related to the Jacobian is not right. A function may have a vanishing Jacobian, or even worse no Jacobian at all (if it is not differentiable) and be invertible. Take the example of $f : x \mapsto x^3$ whose Jacobian vanishes at $0$.

Comment: How is it one-one in case 2 and 4?

Comment: I modified my answer as the first part was right, but not the second one.

Comment: Are you sure only options 2 and 4 are correct?

Comment: Now I'm wrong. I just let the correct part of my answer.

Comment: In all 4 cases we can show that $f$ is not one-one, thus not invertible in any of the given domains,but don't you think most suitable answer would be 2 and 4, because in these two cases $f$  is at least locally invertible ?